# Redirecionamento se não estiver logado Auth CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, autenticação, auth

Estou com uma pequena dúvida.

Configurei o beforeFilter corretamente para que permita o acesso às actions devidas.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte. Quanto tento acessar uma determinada action em um determinado controller, a aplicação está me direcionando para ...admin/login, onde eu faria o login, mas o correto seria para login/index.

Onde configuro este redirecionamento para que os usuários não logados sejam redirecionados para "login/index"?

Imagino que seja algo aqui neste arquivo. Se alguém puder me ajudar ficarei grato.

**AppController.php:**

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

    class AppController extends Controller {

        public $components = array(

            "Session",
            "Auth" => array(

                'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'imagens'),
                'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'login'),
                'authError' => "Você não pode acessar essa página",
                "authorize" => array('Controller'),
                'authenticate' => array(
                    'all' => array(
                        'userModel' => 'Login'
                    ),
                    'Form' => array(
                        'fields' => array(
                          'username' => 'username', //Default is 'username' in the userModel
                          'password' => 'password'  //Default is 'password' in the userModel
                        )
                    )
                ),

            )

        );

        public function isAuthorized($login){
            return true;
        }

        public function beforeFilter(){
            if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
            $this->Auth->allow('index');
            $this->set('logged_in', $this->Auth->loggedIn());
            $this->set('current_user', $this->Auth->user());
        }

    }
```

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse link, tem um método logout:
http://pastebin.com/RmZLhDRG